# Crash after updates

Tags: grub2, crash, stable-release-updates

I was doing standard updates on Ubuntu 14.04, meanwhile I was writing some email when it switched off and this appear:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/60JZD.jpg
GNU GRUB! 
I remember that it was part of the update... 
What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I boot from grub following these instructions:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140616032147/http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux
My OS started.
From there I made via terminal `sudo update-grub`.
This worked fine for me!

**Update, since the blog post went removed:**

**GRUB 2 Command Shell**

The GRUB 2 command shell is just as powerful as the shell in legacy GRUB. You can use it to discover boot images, kernels, and root filesystems. In fact, it gives you complete access to all filesystems on the local machine regardless of permissions or other protections. Which some might consider a security hole, but you know the old Unix dictum: whoever has physical access to the machine owns it.

When you're at the `grub>` prompt, you have a lot of functionality similar to any command shell such as history and tab-completion. The grub rescue> mode is more limited, with no history and no tab-completion.

If you are practicing on a functioning system, press C when your GRUB boot menu appears to open the GRUB command shell. You can stop the bootup countdown by scrolling up and down your menu entries with the arrow keys. It is safe to experiment at the GRUB command line because nothing you do there is permanent. If you are already staring at the grub> or grub rescue>prompt then you're ready to rock.

The next few commands work with both grub> and grub rescue>. The first command you should run invokes the pager, for paging long command outputs:

```
grub> set pager=1
```

There must be no spaces on either side of the equals sign. Now let's do a little exploring. Type ls to list all partitions that GRUB sees:

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

What's all this msdos stuff? That means this system has the old-style MS-DOS partition table, rather than the shiny new Globally Unique Identifiers partition table (GPT). (See Using the New GUID Partition Table in Linux (Goodbye Ancient MBR). If you're running GPT it will say (hd0,gpt1). Now let's snoop. Use the ls command to see what files are on your system:

```
grub> ls (hd0,1)/
lost+found/ bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/
lib64/ media/ mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin/ 
srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ vmlinuz vmlinuz.old 
initrd.img initrd.img.old
```

Hurrah, we have found the root filesystem. You can omit the msdos and gpt labels. If you leave off the slash it will print information about the partition. You can read any file on the system with the cat command:

```
grub> cat (hd0,1)/etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l
```

Reading /etc/issue could be useful on a multi-boot system for identifying your various Linuxes.

**Booting From grub>**

This is how to set the boot files and boot the system from the grub> prompt. We know from running the ls command that there is a Linux root filesystem on (hd0,1), and you can keep searching until you verify where /boot/grub is. Then run these commands, using your own root partition, kernel, and initrd image:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub> boot
```

The first line sets the partition that the root filesystem is on. The second line tells GRUB the location of the kernel you want to use. Start typing /boot/vmli, and then use tab-completion to fill in the rest. Type root=/dev/sdX to set the location of the root filesystem. Yes, this seems redundant, but if you leave this out you'll get a kernel panic. How do you know the correct partition? hd0,1 = /dev/sda1. hd1,1 = /dev/sdb1. hd3,2 = /dev/sdd2. I think you can extrapolate the rest.

The third line sets the initrd file, which must be the same version number as the kernel.

The fourth line boots your system.

On some Linux systems the current kernels and initrds are symlinked into the top level of the root filesystem:

```
$ ls -l /
vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
```

So you could boot from grub> like this:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

**Booting From grub-rescue>**

If you're in the GRUB rescue shell the commands are different, and you have to load the normal.mod andlinux.mod modules:

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,1)
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
grub rescue> insmod linux
grub rescue> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub rescue> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub rescue> boot
```

Tab-completion should start working after you load both modules.

**Making Permanent Repairs**

When you have successfully booted your system, run these commands to fix GRUB permanently:

```
# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /usr/share/images/grub/Apollo_17_The_Last_Moon_Shot_Edit1.tga
Found background image: /usr/share/images/grub/Apollo_17_The_Last_Moon_Shot_Edit1.tga
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

When you run grub-install remember you're installing it to the boot sector of your hard drive and not to a partition, so do not use a partition number like /dev/sda1.

Comment: Glad! that you solved your problem.

Comment: This is now a dead link

Comment: Sorry, here it is the content https://web.archive.org/web/20140616032147/http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux

Comment: And I've edited the answer to contains the real answer!

Answer (score 2):

This looks rather bad.

GRUB is a bootloader - it initializes your OS after the hardware has been organized by the BIOS.

Either you have a serious problem, or you need just do download GRUB, put it on a CD or USB stick and flash your current version of Grub. Given your rare information, this is all i can say about this.

How to do this: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Installation

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your GRUB as you have already stated and can be solved. Also as you already know, it is caused due to incomplete update.

**Pre-requisities:**

1. Exact same version of LiveISO as of your current Ubuntu version. It is better if you have an internet connection.

Now, from [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd):

1. Boot to your Live Ubuntu and then select 'Try Ubuntu'.
2. Open terminal and type:

   `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`

   **Where X is the letter of your Ubuntu installed partition such as a or b. If you are confused, open Gparted while still in Live environment and look for your ext4 partition.**

   **And Y is the number. If it is a primary partition then, it will be any one of these: 1, 2, 3, 4 & if it is a logical partition then it should start with 5 & so on.**
3. Now, type:

   > sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
   >
   > sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
   >
   > sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
   >
   > sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
4. Next, type:

   `sudo chroot /mnt`
5. Then:

   `grub-install /dev/sdX` **remember to change X**
6. Now, update grub:

   `update-grub`
7. Finally, type these to exit:

   > exit &&
   >
   > sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
   >
   > sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
   >
   > sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
   >
   > sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
   >
   > sudo umount /mnt
8. And, reboot.

This should solve your problem, if your problem still exists, then comment below.

Comment: It doesn't work to me. I add a new answer that works. Thank you.